# Open Form to a New Record in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

My goal is to have all of the command buttons on my main menu open a form right to a new record for entry. However, I already have a code that works perfectly so all the forms open right to a new entry, and I can still navigate to previous entries. EXCEPT for one. I've double and triple checked this against the other codes, and there are no differences. For some reason though, this one form (I'm just going to call it "Form" for the purpose of this question) opens to the first record, rather than a new one. Below is the code I'm using that doesn't work, (even though it's the same as my other ones that do work.)

```
Private Sub Command13_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command13_Click

   Dim stDocName As String
   Dim stLinkCriteria As String

   stDocName = "Form"
   DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria
   DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

Exit_Command13_Click:
   Exit Sub

Err_Command13_Click:
   MsgBox Err.Description
   Resume Exit_Command13_Click

End Sub
```

Surely this is a simple fix, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: Is `Allow Additions` = yes? Anything else that prevents a new record (query allows add)?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly calling the object? `DoCmd.GoToRecord , stDocName, acNewRec`

Comment: @Hans Why did you delete? I think it's important to show people the best way to do it. `DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, stDocName, acNewRec` is more readable and you don't get trapped, if the form is not active for any reason.

Comment: Have you tried to add `DoCmd.GoToRecord , stDocName, acNewRec` to the form's **On Open** event instead of using it on the button's click event? I think it would be worth a try.

Comment: Breanne, can you manually navigate to the new record in form "Form"?

Comment: What happens if you try using the `1=0` as a where condition argument? `DoCmd.OpenForm "Form", acNormal, , "1 = 0", , acDialog`

Comment: I used @Huntdogg 's solution, and it worked! However, I do wish I understood why it was the only form that didn't work with my other code (I've compared properties side by side and they're the exact same, as well as the table it shoots to). "Allow Additions" is turned on. And I can manually navigate to the new record, I just wanted it automatic like the others. (just to answer the other questions). If it's likely not an issue that will have later consequences for not examining further, I'll leave it be. Just wanted feedback if I should investigate beyond this "quick fix"?

Comment: What is your `stLinkCriteria`? The cause may be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the *DoCmd.GoToRecord Method* help topic ...

> If you leave the *objecttype* and *objectname* arguments blank (the
>   default constant, **acActiveDataObject**, is assumed for *objecttype*), the
>   active object is assumed.

Usually `DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName` should make `stDocName` the active object, which would mean `GoToRecord` should then be applied against that form.  And you indicated that's what happens with your other forms.

However, since it isn't working in this case, give `GoToRecord` values for both the *objecttype* and *objectname* arguments:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria
'DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, stDocName, acNewRec
```

One puzzling point is that `stLinkCriteria` is an empty string.  So it doesn't seem useful to include that when you call `OpenForm`.  But I can't see how that affects the outcome of `GoToRecord`.

Comment: Although your concept is better, it also works without the objectname (tested with 2007). Seems like the form gets active when it opens.